# Open application on top of web page with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When user clicks on *Finish* button, a webpage will open along with the software exe. But the issue is that the web page will always remain on top.

In `Run` section:

```
Filename: "{app}\abc.exe"; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,ABC}; \
  Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent shellexec runasoriginaluser runmaximized; \
  WorkingDir: {app}
```

Requirement is that the exe needs to be on top.

The code I followed to open a webpage:

```pascal
const insSiteURLEN = 'https://example.com';

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep); 
var ErrorCode: Integer;
begin 
  if CurStep=ssDone then 
  begin 
    ShellExec('', insSiteURLEN, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode); 
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is hard to achieve. You are starting two applications in parallel. The one that manages to open its window first will get overshadowed by the one that takes longer to open.

You are definitely not helping it by opening the webpage *later* than the application – `CurStepChanged(ssDone)` is triggered after running the `postinstall` `Run` entries. Move the web page opening code to the [`NextButtonClick(wpFinished)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick).

Though even that will not guarantee that the application opens on the top of the browser. It just makes it more likely.

Btw, it would be even more easy to implement, if you open the webpage via `Run`. That would even allow the user to decide if s/he want to open the webpage at all.